# Google Search Console reports only two back links after Wix enabled HTTPS

Tags: google-search-console, https, backlinks, wix

I just noticed that my back links (in Google Webmaster Console) dropped from 60 to 2.

After investigation I found that WIX has enabled HTTPS a couple of days ago.
Anyone knows if this should be the reason?

Btw, I have put things back as they were. I disabled the HTTPS in WIX configuration.

Comment: Simply enabling HTTPS wouldn't result in an immediate drop in reported backlinks. Was an HTTP to HTTPS redirect implemented? "i have put things back as they were." - What does that mean? Have you disabled HTTPS?? Is your problem now resolved???

Comment: You should add all variations in GWC, e.g normally 4 in total: `non-www`, `www`, `http` and `https`. As  mentioned by @w3dk 301 redirect old to new, then it doesn't matter which variation Google lists those backlinks under.

Comment: By putting back I mean: I disabled the https in WIX configuration. Btw, i never implemented the redirect. What do you mean by GWC please? So, from what I understand I just have to re-enable the https and 301 redirects and things should work again? How long do you think it will take to see the result please?

Comment: Currently, the problem is still there.

Comment: Calm down, checkout the backlinks, click on it, and if it is redirect to https version, then everything is fine. Search console take some time to get data. Stephen is right, Google may already know about that links, but they have some delay to report you on your dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

The links to your site section of Google Search Console is not very reliable.  The links may all be there, and Google just isn't displaying them.   When that happens Google still knows about them and is counting them towards your site's reputation.

From [Google's help document about links to your site](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/55281?hl=en) (emphasis added):

> **Not all links to your site may be listed**. This is normal. In addition, Google has recently made improvements to how we gather and display link data (for example, link counts now include links redirected using 301 or 302 redirects). As a result, **you may see a change in the number of links** displayed for your site.

I'd recommend that you re-enable HTTPS for your site.   When the option is available, there is no reason to keep using HTTP these days.   When HTTPS is enabled, make sure you add your site to Google Search Console a second time with `https://`.  It is possible that your links would have just moved over to that profile in search console.